# Apache wildcard SSL configuration alongside organisational SSL for same domain

Tags: apache, ssl, wildcard-subdomain, apache2.2

I have limited experience setting up SSL certs, so far i've been able to get single SSL certs working on different servers, now I'm stuck trying to get a wildcard SSL cert setup alongside an existing organisational SSL for same domain, it keeps pointing at the organisational cert even though I specify the wildcard cert in the the virtual host.

I'll try explain the best I can using sample data:

- organisational certificate `site.example.com`
- wildcard certificate `*.example.com`

`apache version 2.2.3`

I will leave out the port 80 stuff as there is no issues there

Example configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost 192.0.2.201:443
NameVirtualHost 192.0.2.202:443

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.202:443>
    ServerName site.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /locationof/organisational.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /locationof/organisational.intermediate.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /locationof/organisational.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.202:443>
    ServerName  mytestsite.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mytestsite

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /locationof/wildcard.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /locationof/wildcard.intermediate.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /locationof/wildcard.key
</VirtualHost>
```

There are no issues with either certificate.

When I restart Apache and go to `https://mytestsite.example.com` in Firefox it tells me 'Your connection is not sercure' when expanding the Advanced button I can see from the message 'The certificate is only valid for the following names: site.example.com, www.site.example.com'  So I guess it's picking up the organisational virtual host each time and isn't getting to the wildcard virtual host, I've tried switching them about as I've read that Apache can be affected by the order of the virtual hosts but it made no difference to me.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong but I've searched various sites and Google but just can't pinpoint the issue :(

EDIT - additional info from running `httpd -S`

```
192.0.2..201:443       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.anothersite.net (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:aaaa)
         port 443 namevhost www.anothersite.net (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:aaaa)

192.0.2.202:443       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server site.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:xxxx)
         port 443 namevhost site.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:xxxx)
         port 443 namevhost mytestsite.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:yyyy)

                 wild alias *.*
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server someoldsite.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:xx)
         port 443 namevhost someoldsite.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:xx)
         // there is no virtual host for this old site, it seems it is the name of the server inside /etc/hosts file
```

I checked the `*:443` path in case there was a redirect or something like that but there is not.  I've added in the additional NameVirtualHost settings to example configuration.  From the info above I'm still not sure what's going wrong!  The wildcard SSL certificate is set up on 2 other servers and works fine but it is the only SSL certificates on those servers as opposed to this server which has 2 others and 1 sharing the same domain

EDIT 2
there is a ssl.conf file being include with the following `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` but don't think that is causing any harm?

this server has been working fine using both certs on .201 and .202 and the wildcard cert works fine on two other servers, I just can't get the wildcard ssl cert to work along with the .202 organisational cert :(

Comment: Which version of Apache? Before Apache 2.3 you need a `NameVirtualHost` directive otherwise HTTPS hosts on same IP will not work (that is will work like you observe, that is not like you want).

Comment: Yes I have the NameVirtualHost set in the file, apache version is 2.2, I've updated the question to include this information.

Comment: Try `apachectl` to test the configuration and `httpd -S` to see the dump of virtualhost. Make sure to reread https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html   Double check that all certificate paths do indeed correspond to the proper certificate.

Comment: apachectl configtest shows syntax OK, have updated question above with httpd -S results, all looks fine I think!  Still stumped on what is causing the problem